# Changing group_type to mailinglist fails with unknown db error / deadlock

Tags: groups, error, mailing

Hejdo,

Today I just wanted to make some of our groups accessible by CiviMail by checking the mailinglist group type checkbox. But this took long time (more than 10 minutes) no matter if I did this for a group with about 10 or about 2k contacts. I also tried via group api, same same.

The ui ajax call responds with error and the corresponding log entry states:

```
"DB Error: unknown error", -1, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT IGNORE INTO civicrm_group_contact_cache (group_id,contact_id) VALUES (...")
[...]
Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

We have somewhere around 180k contacts and 2k groups. Civi is 4.6.10. CMS is current Drupal 7, DB is Mysql 5.5.46.

Any ideas on how to solve it or investigate on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like corrupt tables or a stuck MySQL process.

If you have access to phpMyAdmin, you can select all tables at the bottom and then choose "repair tables".

If you do not have phpMyAdmin, but you have access to ssh then you can use mysqlrepair (or mysqlcheck -r), see more at http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/mysqlcheck1.html

If you have neither you should ask your hoster to do a repair for all tables.

Besides that, restarting MySQL makes sense.

If you need further MySQL tweaking, please look at http://mysqltuner.com/
Nothing I have seen beats that script.

Comment: Thanks a load! Besides that, do you know if changing the group type to include mailinglist should always take so long? What's happening behind the scenes?

Comment: no, should be a breaze, as far as I know it's only one field updated.

Comment: Hmm, lasts minutes for small groups. Do you think it would be fine to update this field in the db for sepecified groups?

Comment: Did repair tables and restart have an effect? If not then I guess we should have a look at mysql config. 180K Contacts and 2K Groups get to the scale that default config might not be optimal.

Comment: Yeah, effect was:  no errors anymore.
But changing to mailinglist keeps working incredibly slow. 
I did some optimizations in mysql server config but I'd appreciate some tips.

Comment: See update :) http://mysqltuner.com/ has quite often been a life saver for me.